# HEREAPI Maps not display in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, here-api

why can't maps appear, as if it was blocked from net. i don't know how to fix it.
[image]

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'apikey': '{API-KEY}'
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    defaultLayers.vector.normal.map);
```

Comment: 401 error is due to permission issue. For some reason your application is not able to load some script files and as a result having errors in js codes. Its either an issue with the google map account that you are using or your web server where the script loading is being blocked.

Comment: When I first created the entry, I used the appid as an api key, and the same error occurred. Please follow the steps below to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Please login your here developer home page, and find below content.**

[image]

**2. You can click `create API key` button, and use it in your code.**

[image]

**3. Then you can run your project to test.**

[image]

[image]